# Enforce foreign key constraint with condition

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables in SQL Server, `users` and `operations`.

`Operation` table has two relationship with `users`:

1. `UserID`
2. `ManagerUserID`

`UserID` always enforces existing data in the `USERS` table. But `ManagerUserID` is set to 0 (zero) when inserting, and the manager approving this operation must enforce data in `USER` table.

How to do set foreign key for `ManagerUserID`?

I don't want a record in `users` table with `userID = 0`

Comment: You either set null for managerUserID at insert time (foreign keys) can be null, or you have to have a UserID that matches in the Users table. That's how foreign keys work. Your solution of having a "dummy" user zero to enable entering zero as a ManagerUserID is an option too, although I don't really understand the requirement to set zero for ManagerUserID as making any sense here. I would push back on that. And of course you can NOT have the foreign key relationship defined from ManagerUserID to Users, as another option (but you lose the integrity check in that case).

Comment: Why does it need to be zero why not null?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.